# When Selecting a .png Image Always showing black background in android using React Native

Tags: android, image, react-native, background, png

In my React Native app i have to pick .png image with transparent background but when i select it from android device it is selecting the image with black background.
[image: I have selected 2 images with .png extension but showing black background]

please help regarding the issue.

Comment: I also had that issue, My mistake was the `backgroundColor` property applied to that image.